# Redefining the \part environment to add a page border

Tags: sectioning, framed, parts

1. How can I redefine the \part environment, in a book documentclass, to add a page border at the page margins?
2. By the way, it must be possible (since everything is possible in LaTeX) to get a shaded page border with thicker left and lower lines.

The first question is more important to me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One possibility using `TikZ`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\def\@part[#1]#2{%
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax
      \refstepcounter{part}%
      \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\thepart\hspace{1em}#1}%
    \else
      \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1}%
    \fi
    \markboth{}{}%
    {\centering
     \interlinepenalty \@M
     \normalfont
     \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax
       \huge\bfseries \partname\nobreakspace\thepart
       \par
       \vskip 20\p@
     \fi
     \Huge \bfseries #2\par
    \noindent
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]% 
      \fill [red!20!black]
([xshift=-10pt]current page.south east)
rectangle
(current page.north east);
      \fill [red!20!black]
(current page.north east)
rectangle
([yshift=-10pt]current page.north west);
      \fill [red!20!black]
(current page.south east)
rectangle
([yshift=20pt]current page.south west);
      \fill [red!20!black]
(current page.south west)
rectangle
([xshift=20pt]current page.north west);
    \end{tikzpicture}}%
    \@endpart}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\part{Test Part}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A variation using a shading:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\def\@part[#1]#2{%
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax
      \refstepcounter{part}%
      \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\thepart\hspace{1em}#1}%
    \else
      \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1}%
    \fi
    \markboth{}{}%
    {\centering
     \interlinepenalty \@M
     \normalfont
     \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax
       \huge\bfseries \partname\nobreakspace\thepart
       \par
       \vskip 20\p@
     \fi
     \Huge \bfseries #2\par
    \noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]% 
\shade [shading=ball,ball color=cyan!80!black]
  (current page.south west) -- ([xshift=20pt]current page.south west) -- ([xshift=20pt,yshift=-10pt]current page.north west) -- ([xshift=-10pt,yshift=-10pt]current page.north east) -- 
([xshift=-10pt,yshift=20pt]current page.south east) --
([xshift=-10pt,yshift=20pt]current page.south west) --
([xshift=-10pt]current page.south west) --
(current page.south east) --
(current page.north east) --
(current page.north west) -- cycle
;
\end{tikzpicture}}%
    \@endpart}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\part{Test Part}

\end{document}
```

[image]

After a comment, it's clear that the frame should go around the text area; in this case, using the [`tikzpagenodes`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikzpagenodes) package, one can make a simple modification to the solutions above and get the desires result by using the `current page text area` family of nodes:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}

\makeatletter
\def\@part[#1]#2{%
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax
      \refstepcounter{part}%
      \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\thepart\hspace{1em}#1}%
    \else
      \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1}%
    \fi
    \markboth{}{}%
    {\centering
     \interlinepenalty \@M
     \normalfont
     \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax
       \huge\bfseries \partname\nobreakspace\thepart
       \par
       \vskip 20\p@
     \fi
     \Huge \bfseries #2\par
    \noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]% 
\shade [shading=ball,ball color=cyan!80!black]
(current page text area.south west) -- 
([xshift=20pt]current page text area.south west) -- 
([xshift=20pt,yshift=-10pt]current page text area.north west) -- 
([xshift=-10pt,yshift=-10pt]current page text area.north east) -- 
([xshift=-10pt,yshift=20pt]current page text area.south east) --
([xshift=10pt,yshift=20pt]current page text area.south west) --
([xshift=10pt]current page text area.south west) --
(current page text area.south east) --
(current page text area.north east) --
(current page text area.north west) -- cycle
;
\end{tikzpicture}}%
    \@endpart}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\part{Test Part}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A second frame has been requested in a comment; here's one possibility for this second frame:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}

\makeatletter
\def\@part[#1]#2{%
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax
      \refstepcounter{part}%
      \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\thepart\hspace{1em}#1}%
    \else
      \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1}%
    \fi
    \markboth{}{}%
    {\centering
     \interlinepenalty \@M
     \normalfont
     \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax
       \huge\bfseries \partname\nobreakspace\thepart
       \par
       \vskip 20\p@
     \fi
     \Huge \bfseries #2\par
    \noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]% 
\shade [shading=ball,ball color=cyan!80!black]
(current page text area.south west) -- 
([xshift=20pt]current page text area.south west) -- 
([xshift=20pt,yshift=-10pt]current page text area.north west) -- 
([xshift=-10pt,yshift=-10pt]current page text area.north east) -- 
([xshift=-10pt,yshift=20pt]current page text area.south east) --
([xshift=10pt,yshift=20pt]current page text area.south west) --
([xshift=10pt]current page text area.south west) --
(current page text area.south east) --
(current page text area.north east) --
(current page text area.north west) -- cycle
;
\shade [shading=ball,ball color=cyan!80!black]
([xshift=24pt,yshift=24pt]current page text area.south west) -- 
([xshift=40pt,yshift=24pt]current page text area.south west) -- 
([xshift=40pt,yshift=-22pt]current page text area.north west) -- 
([xshift=-22pt,yshift=-22pt]current page text area.north east) -- 
([xshift=-22pt,yshift=40pt]current page text area.south east) --
([xshift=30pt,yshift=40pt]current page text area.south west) --
([xshift=24pt,yshift=24pt]current page text area.south west) --
([xshift=-14pt,yshift=24pt]current page text area.south east) --
([xshift=-14pt,yshift=-14pt]current page text area.north east) --
([xshift=24pt,yshift=-14pt]current page text area.north west) -- cycle
;
\end{tikzpicture}}%
    \@endpart}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\part{Test Part}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much @Gonzalo Medina. The desired page border (or page frame) is at the margins, not at the borders of the paper. I have about 2.54cm (1 in) of page margins at each side (standard margins of the book document class).

Comment: @rasha the idea is still the same and the `tikzpagenodes` package facilitates this job. Please see the last example in my updated answer.

Comment: your last example answers perfectly my question. Thank you very much. I have a last question regarding this subject. How to set up two nested frames (like the last frame) distant from one another by a couple of millimeters? I do not see in the LaTeX code you proposed how to set the position of an additional frame (I'm not used to handle such codes, sorry).

Comment: @rasha No problem; please see my updated answer.